# Viewing and labeling specific columns from a txt file, parsing the data

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

I have a dataset with multiple columns and I am only interested in analyzing the data from six of the columns (0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7). I would like to label them with the headings (time, mode, event, xcoord, ycoord, phi).  There are ten columns total, Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
1385940076332   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076336   2   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076339   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076342   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076346   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076350   2   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076353   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1385940076356   3   M   subject_avatar  -30.000000  1.000000    -59.028107  180.000000  0.000000    0.000000
```

When I use the following code to parse the data into columns, it only appears to count the data- but I would like to be able to list the data for further analysis. Here is the code I am using from @alko:

```
with open('/Users/Lab/Desktop/test.txt', 'r') as infile:
f = infile.readlines()
with open('filtered.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in f:
            if 'subject_avatar' in line: #this line is just to take the relevant rows
                outfile.write(line)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filtered.txt', header=None, false_values=None, sep='\s+')[[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]]
df.columns = ['time', 'mode', 'event', 'xcoord', 'ycoord', 'phi']
print df
```

Here is what that code returns:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
Int64Index: 115534 entries, 0 to 115533
Data columns (total 6 columns): 
time      115534  non-null values
mode      115534  non-null values
event     115534  non-null values
xcoord    115534  non-null values
ycoord    115534  non-null values
phi       115534  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2), object(1)
```

I looked up the pandas documentation, and tried df.values, and df.index, but none of these will print the correct data (which would be the 6 columns with the correct headers)

Comment: I think this may have worked (although you could have simply read the whole thing in and then dropped the non-M events from within `pandas`, if I understand you).  That's what `pandas` shows when there's too much data to be conveniently displayed.  Does `print df.head()` look okay?

Comment: Yes, thank you I did not realize that the data was too big to be displayed, but 'print df.head()' looks like this: '    time  mode event  xcoord     ycoord  phi
0  1386865557676     1     M       0  30.526506  180
1  1386865557679     1     M       0  30.526506  180
2  1386865557680     2     M       0  30.526506  180
3  1386865557682     1     M       0  30.526506  180
4  1386865557684     1     M       0  30.526506  180', which is what I want. Also, it looks like I did successfully drop the non 'M' events, which was the goal. Thank you!